# AWS lambda html-pdf phantomjs "Error: write EPIPE" on NodeJS 12.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, phantomjs, html-pdf

I have been using html-pdf (phantomjs) for creating PDF on AWS Lambda with NodeJS 8.0 and it was working fine. Since AWS Lambda has stopped support on NodeJS 8.0 we have updated our NodeJS version to the latest 12.x and we are now getting the following error when we run out PDF Lambda function:

> `{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"write EPIPE","code":"EPIPE","errno":"EPIPE","syscall":"write","stack":["Error: write EPIPE","    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)","    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)","    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:784:11)","    at Socket._write (net.js:796:8)","    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)","    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)","    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)","    at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:141:15)","    at PDF.PdfToBuffer [as toBuffer] (/var/task/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:44:8)","    at /var/task/index.js:121:38"]}`

```
phantomPath: './phantomjs_lambda/phantomjs'
```

```
process.env.FONTCONFIG_PATH='/var/task/fonts'
```

I tried to check similar issues in StackOverflow. I have pointed the phantomjs path correctly, also have the fontconfig in place. We are now stuck as we are unable to update the Lambda function. Any help will be highly appreciated.

*Update: 
Changed the path to phantomjs binary:*

`phantomPath: './node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs'`

After changing the path to phantomjs binary, the error has changed to:

```
{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"write EPIPE","code":"EPIPE","errno":"EPIPE","syscall":"write","stack":["Error: write EPIPE","    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16)"]}
```

Comment: did you find any solutions for the above problem

Comment: No @NarendraChouhan, I have updated my AWS Lambda to use Chrome headless browser (Puppeteer library) instead of PhantomJS. I am now able to generate my PDFs without any issues.

Comment: really thanks for your reply, can you share with some reference link, to  updated my AWS Lambda to use Chrome headless browser and the library link @manmeet

Comment: @NarendraChouhan here you go.. https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-node-puppeteer/

Comment: @NarendraChouhan library page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer
YouTube video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPSlnk0ZzMU

Hope this helps.

Comment: really thanks @manmeet, will try this solution today only

Answer (score 3):

I recently face this issue as well, when i have update Node version of lambda to **14.x**. After following below steps i can able to resolved my issue.

I passed `phantomPath : "./node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs"` at `pdf.create(html,tempParamms)`

- get all files from this Repo: https://github.com/naeemshaikh27/phantom-lambda-fontconfig-pack
- Copy all `.so` files and paste them in your project root.
- Create a directory called `fonts` in your project root.
- Copy all files apart from `.so` files and paste all files in newly created `fonts` directory.
- Replace below code from file `fonts/fonts.conf`.
- Add Lambda Environment Variable `FONTCONFIG_PATH` with value = `/var/task/fonts`
- Upload code to Lambda.

**fonts/fonts.conf**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/var/task/fonts/</dir>
  <cachedir>/tmp/fonts-cache/</cachedir>
  <config></config>
   <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>rgb</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintslight</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
   <const>lcddefault</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Ref : [Link](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/547)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this Error because AWS pull out basic utilities in the environment from node 10.x to 12.x (eg ImageMagick).

The solution is to either include the missing functionality your self or use lambda layers. Here is information on lambda layers with ImageMagic https://github.com/serverlesspub/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2

For further reading on this problem I suggest looking into the AWS forum here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=305691

Answer (score 0):

html-pdf use a npm package phantomjs-prebuilt

phantomjs-prebuilt will automatically install phantomjs for you based on your OS/Archritecture

It's important that the node_modules doesn't get copied over to the docker image
And rather get installed on the docker image itself

I have created custom docker image for azure, for AWS you would need to do the same https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html

Following the this thread you would need to install a couple of dependencies as well https://gist.github.com/julionc/7476620

Ensure you have node_modules/ in your .dockerignore file

```sh
node_modules/
```

Docker file for azure functions (Should create simular dockerfile for AWS lambdas)

```sh
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node12-appservice

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install build-essential chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev -y

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true \
    OPENSSL_CONF=/etc/ssl/

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot


RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install
```

Adding the OPENSS_CONF=/etc/ssl/ is essential as phantomjs will throw another error